# Why Image is not showing in the browser in Material-UI Avatar component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI Avatar React component to show profile images. While compiling it can reach the image, there is no error in compile time. But image is not showing in the browser.

[Please check this image to better understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzQFu.png)

**Codes**:

```
import {avatar} from '../../images/avatar.png';

<Box component='div'>
     <Avatar src={avatar} alt="Russel Crow"/>
</Box>
```

Please tell me why image is not showing in the browser and How to show it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You used a named import, try it like this:

```
import avatar from '../../images/avatar.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with inline url.

Try to run like this

```
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';

   <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Badge, Box, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import { Theme, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

import avatarIcon from  "../../assets/avatar.png"; // or -> import avatarIcon from "@assets/avatar.png";
interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const AvatarCustom: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Stack flexDirection={"column"} alignItems={"center"}>
          <Box sx={{ background: (theme) => theme.palette.backgroundColor.secondary, borderRadius: 3, padding: 2, margin: 2 }}> 
            <Badge
                  overlap="circular"
                  anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
                  variant="dot"
                  sx={{ border: "0px solid white", width:"fit-content", }}
              >
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={avatarIcon} id="avatar" className={classes.avatar}  /> 
                
              </Badge>
              
          </Box>

      </Stack>
    )
}

export default AvatarCustom;
```